# HTML5 file upload fails in IE9

Tags: html, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

Following code works fine in Chrome, but fails in IE9 - in `processFiles()` when we retrieve selected files `e.target.files` is `null`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
</header>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="uploader"/>

    <script>        
        var uploader = document.getElementById ("uploader");
        if (uploader.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9
            uploader.addEventListener ("change", processFiles, false);
        }
        else {
            if (uploader.attachEvent) {   // IE before version 9
                uploader.attachEvent ("change", processFiles);
            }
        }       

        function processFiles(e)
        {

            var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

            for (var i = 0 ; i < files.length ; i ++)
            {
                window.console && console.log && console.log(files[i].name);
            }           
        }       
    </script>   
<body>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code assumes support for the File API.  The first version of IE to support the File API is IE10.  Your code will never work cross-browser as it stands now.

Consider using [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com) which already handles uploads cross-browser and includes a number of useful features.